# Removing an element from a parsed XML tree disrupts iteration

Tags: python, xml

I want to parse an xml file, then process the result tree by removing selected elements.  My problem is that removing an element disrupts the loop that iterates over the elements.

Consider the following xml data:

```
<results>
    <group>
        <a />
        <b />
        <c />
    </group>
</results>
```

and the code:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def showGroup(group,s):
    print(s + '  len=' + str(len(group)))
    print('<group>' )
    for e in group:
        print('   <' + e.tag + '>')
    print('</group>\n')

def processGroup(group):
    for e in group:
        if e.tag != 'a':
            group.remove(e)
            showGroup(group,'removed <' + e.tag + '>')

tree = ET.parse('x.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for group in root:
    processGroup(group)
```

I expected the for loop to process elements `<a>`, `<b>`, and `<c>` in order.  In particular:

1. processing `<a>` should not remove any element
2. processing `<b>` should remove `<b>`
3. processing `<c>` should remove `<c>`

I expected the resulting tree to have a single element inside `<group>` (the `<a>` element), and that len(group) would return 1.

Instead, after processing `<b>`, the for loop decides the end test has been met, and it does not process element `<c>`.  If it did, `<c>` would be removed.  Instead, I am left with a tree with elements `<a>` and `<c>`, and len(group) returns 2.

### What do I need to do to process all three elements while removing selected elements? PS: any comments on style or better ways to do something are welcome.

Update: an ugly hack "fixes" the problem at the cost of some efficiency, if there is no code after removing the element.  But in my real program, there is a lot of code after the pruning loop.

```
for e in group:
    if e.tag != 'a':
        group.remove(e)
        showGroup(group,'removed <' + e.tag + '>')
        processGroup(group)
```

I assume that if the for loop is disrupted, then starting again with the group at the beginning might solve the problem. Recursion is a tidy way of doing that - at the expense of reprocessing all elements that have already been checked but not removed.

I am not satisfied with this solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is you are removing elements from something you are iterating over, when you remove an element the remaining elements get shifted  so you can end up removing the incorrect elements:

A  simple solution is to iterate over a copy of the tree or use *reversed*:

copy:

```
 def processGroup(group):
    # creates a shallow copy so we are removing from the original
    # but iterating over a copy. 
    for e in group[:]:
        if e.tag != 'a':
            group.remove(e)
            showGroup(group,'removed <' + e.tag + '>')
```

reversed:

```
def processGroup(group):
    # starts at the end, as the container shrinks.
    # when an element is removed, we still see
    # elements at the same position when we started out loop.
    for e in reversed(group):
        if e.tag != 'a':
            group.remove(e)
            showGroup(group,'removed <' + e.tag + '>')
```

using the copy logic:

```
In [7]: tree = ET.parse('test.xml')

In [8]: root = tree.getroot()

In [9]: for group in root:
   ...:         processGroup(group)
   ...:     
removed <b>  len=2
<group>
   <a>
   <c>
</group>

removed <c>  len=1
<group>
   <a>
</group>
```

You can also use `ET.tostring` in place of your for loop:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

def show_group(group,s):
    print(s + '  len=' + str(len(group)))
    print(ET.tostring(group))


def process_group(group):
    for e in group[:]:
        if e.tag != 'a':
            group.remove(e)
            show_group(group, 'removed <' + e.tag + '>')

tree = ET.parse('test.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

for group in root.findall(".//group"):
    process_group(group)
```

Comment: It seems really elegant that this fix could be done by adding three characters.  I had to go read up on slicing lists to understand the notation, and that's helpful to this newbie.  I also appreciate the alternative, reversed solution, and knowing about the tostring() function is helpful.

Comment: But I don't understand the block that starts 'copy logic:'.  I don't see what changes were made.  Could you explain?

Comment: Sorry, the copy_logic uses  `for e in group[:]`,  when you remove an element iterating from the left hand,  the following  list elements get shifted so what was say at index 5 is now at index 4, the pointers are not updated from when you started the loop so when you can end up removing the wrong element. With reversed the  elements we have not seen won't be shifted so you don't have the same problem.