# Using Python, trying to save an xml file with hex-coded html escape characters

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, hex, ascii

I am using ElementTree.  I have a parsed xml document that looks like this:

```
<data>
    <name>
        <slash>/</slash>
    </name>
</data>
```

I would like to be able to save it using a hex code for the html escape character.

Since the [hex code](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm) for '/' is 2F, I would like to persist the xml as:

```
<data>
    <name>
        <slash>&#x2f;</slash>
    </name>
</data>
```

What is the pythonic way to do this?  Ideally, I would like this to work:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml_doc = ET.tostring(source,method="xml")

xml_doc=change_to_html_hex_code(xml_doc)

out_file = open("output.xml",'w')
out_file.write(xml_doc)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using lxml:

```
x = """<data>
    <name>
        <slash>/</slash>
    </name>
</data>"""
import lxml.etree as et

xml_doc = et.fromstring(x)
for node in xml_doc.xpath("//*[contains(text(), '/')]"):
    node.text = node.text.replace("/","&#x2f;")



print(et.tostring(xml_doc))
```

Which would give you:

```
<data>
    <name>
        <slash>&amp;#x2f;</slash>
    </name>
</data>
```

Or xml:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree  as et

xml_doc = et.fromstring(x)
for node in xml_doc.iter("*"):
    if "/" in node.text:
        node.text = node.text.replace("/","&#x2f;")
```

To write to the file, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38003030/python-how-to-write-empty-tree-node-as-empty-string-to-xml-file/38003299#38003299) covers both.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the codecs module (included in python)

```
import codecs

def returnHex(input):
    hexitup = codecs.getencoder('hex')
    return ("&#" + hexitup(input)[0]+";")

print(returnHex('/'))
```

This should return &#2f;