# python xml.etree - remove node but keep children (assign children to grandparents)

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing

In Python, how do I remove a node but keep its children using `xml.etree` API?

Yes I know there's an [answer using lxml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15168259/python-xml-remove-some-elements-and-their-children-but-keep-specific-elements-an) but since `xml.etree` is part of Python website, I figure it deserves an answer too.

Original xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data>
```

Let's say I want to remove `country` nodes but keep the children and assign them to the parent of `country`?

Ideally, I want a solution that does things "in place" instead of creating a new tree.

My (non-working) solution:

```
# Get all parents of `country`
for country_parent in root.findall(".//country/.."):
    print(country_parent.tag)
    # Some countries could have same parent so get all
    # `country` nodes of current parent
    for country in country_parent.findall("./country"):
        print('\t', country.tag)
        # For each child of `country`, assign it to parent
        # and then delete it from `parent`
        for country_child in country:
            print('\t\t', country_child.tag)
            country_parent.append(country_child)
            country.remove(country_child)
        country_parent.remove(country)
tree.write("test_mod.xml")
```

Output of my **print** statements:

```
data
     country
         rank
         gdppc
         neighbor
     country
         rank
         gdppc
     country
         rank
         gdppc
         neighbor
```

Right away we can see there's a problem: `country` is missing the tag `year` and some `neighbor` tags.

The resulting `.xml` output:

```
<data>
    <rank>1</rank>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor direction="W" name="Switzerland" />
    <rank>4</rank>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <rank>68</rank>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor direction="E" name="Colombia" />
    </data>
```

This is obviously wrong.

**QUESTION**: Why does this happen?

I can imagine it's from the appending/removing breaking something with the list i.e. I've "invalidated" the list similar to iterator.

Comment: `for country_child in country[:]:` as per the answer linked to in your last question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37702011/removing-an-element-from-a-parsed-xml-tree-disrupts-iteration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line from your program:

```
        country.remove(country_child)
```

The iteration of an `xml.etree.ElementTree.Element` is essentially passed through to the `list` of sub-elements. Modifying that list during iteration will yield odd results.

Comment: Why does that line break things?

Comment: I'm checking on that now. I believe it is for the reason you surmised, that you are modifying the list while you are iterating over it.

Comment: but it's a `list` of elements not an iterator, right?

Comment: The reason why I have that line there is to minimize memory usage. If I remove that line, I'll be temporarily adding sizeof(country's children).

Comment: I don't think you'll be adding any memory. `country_parent.append()` won't create a new `Element`, it will only link in the existing one.

Comment: The line `for country_child in country:` creates an iterator, not a list. If you think you need a list, you could change that line to: `for country_child in list(country):`.

Comment: My understanding of Python iterators is not very good. In `for a in b:`, which one is the iterator assuming this is a top-level for-loop?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9884132/what-exactly-are-pythons-iterator-iterable-and-iteration-protocols

Comment: I've tried reading this but it doesn't make sense; can you rephrase? `The iteration of an xml.etree.ElementTree.Element is essentially passed through to the list of sub-elements.`

Comment: I get that the implementation of an iterator is paramount to the correctness of modifying what it's pointing to. But we're talking about a list; why would deleting list[0] cause the iterator to forget that the next element is list[1]?

Comment: `append()` does add new instance. See `ElementTree.py:Element:append():... self._children.append(subelement)`, `ElementTree.py:Element:__init__:...self._children = []` so it's just a simple list.

Comment: Ping. I don't understand `"The iteration of an xml.etree.ElementTree.Element is essentially passed through to the list of sub-elements. Modifying that list during iteration will yield odd results."` Please rephrase.